# Get weight matrices from gensim word2Vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I am using gensim word2vec package in python.
I would like to retrieve the `W` and `W'` weight matrices that have been learn during the skip-gram learning.

It seems to me that `model.syn0` gives me the first one but I am not sure how I can get the other one. Any idea?

I would actually love to find any exhaustive documentation on models accessible attributes because the official one does not seem to be precise (for instance `syn0` is not described as an attribute)

Comment: I just tried with a small dataset and its giving me the whole embedding matrix `np.shape(model.syn0)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `model.wv.syn0` contains the *input* embedding matrix. *Output* embedding is stored in `model.syn1` when it's trained with [hierarchical softmax](http://building-babylon.net/2017/08/01/hierarchical-softmax/) (`hs=1`) or in `model.syn1neg` when it uses negative sampling (`negative>0`). That's it! When both hierarchical softmax and negative sampling are not enabled, `Word2Vec` uses a single weight matrix `model.wv.syn0` for training.

See also a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42554289/712995).

Answer (score 0):

Use `model.wv.vectors` (not in docs?)